# how can i set Street view for Google map in Android?

Tags: android, maps, google-street-view

For Displaying the street view in the map i am putting the following code:

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

But, it is not executed it shows the following message when i write the method.

The method `setStreetView(boolean)` from the type `MapView` is **deprecated**

Is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No other alternative** yet in place of setStreetView(boolean) method from google api 11 onwards, but if you read document carefully, it will show you blue line if street view is available of particular place

Comment: Can you setSatelliteView(true) in place, but no other alternative for streetView

Comment: But it is not executing it is deprecated?

Comment: yes it will not execute as it is deprecated, I am affraid, why there is no other alternative for deprecated method.. generally java/android provide alternative when one method/class is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

There is NO alternative because `isStreetView(boolean)` is NOT deprecated. I have used this method on several phones running Android 4.0.4 and it works on ALL of them. Perhaps it is deprecated on some phones but not on the Galaxy Nexus. `isStreetView(boolean)` works, so use it.